# Cron trigger for daily Quartz job

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

As usual, I'm having trouble with setting a Cron timer expression for a Quartz job. If I want to run a job daily at 2245 hours, should the expression be:

0 45 22 * * ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Their [tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) is pretty nice though :-)

The field order is

```
second minute hour dayofmonth month dayofweek year
```

Year is an optional field.

`*` means `every` and dayofmonth and dayofweek can also take the `?` value, meaning `no specific value`.  Typically one of the fields will get the `?` value.

So your trigger says:

> On second 0 of minute 45 of hour 22 of any every in the month, every month, 
>   no matter what weekday

Should work.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I really don't like cron expressions.

Comment: * does not mean 'any' it means 'every'

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you wouldn't be asking the question if you didn't have any problem, but the syntax you listed should work:

```
0 45 22 * * ?
```

You're using Quartz's CronTrigger?  These formats would also work:

```
0 45 22 ? * *   
0 45 22 * * ?
```

Answer (score -3):

The correct format is 0 0/45 22 * * ?

[Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) mentioned by [fvu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112079/fvu) was very useful.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I stumbled across this doing some research. This is actually wrong. This format would cause the trigger to fire at both 22:00:00 and 22:45:00 as the 0/45 means start at 0 and repeat every 45 minutes.